# Database indexes - does the table size matter?

Tags: database, database-design, database-indexes

What I mean is: Does a table with 20 columns benefit more from indexing a certain field (one that's used in search-ish queries) than a table that has just 4 columns?

Also: What is the harm in adding index to fields that I don't search with much, but might later in the future? Is there a negative to adding indexes? Is it just the size it takes up on disk, or can it make things run slower to add unnecessary indexes?

**extracted from a comment**

I'm using Postgres (latest version) and I have one table that I'll be doing a lot of LIKE type queries, etc but the values will undoubtedly change often since my clients have access to CRUD. Should I can the idea of indexes? Are they just a headache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does a table with 20 columns benefit more from indexing a certain field (one that's used in search-ish queries) than a table that has just 4 columns?

No, number of columns in a table has no bearing on benefits from having an index.

An index is solely on the values in the column(s) specified; it's the frequency of the values that will impact how much benefit your queries will see.  For example, a column containing a boolean value is a poor choice for indexing, because it's a 50/50 chance the value will be one or the other value.  At a 50/50 split over all the rows, the index doesn't narrow the search for a particular row.

> What is the harm in adding index to fields that I don't search with much, but might later in the future?

Indexes only speed up data retrieval when they can be used, but they negatively impact the speed of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. Indexes also require maintenance to keep their value.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Thanks... Shoot. What sort of maintenance, and how often?

Comment: @orokusaki: Depends on the database, and how often data is changed in columns the indexes are on.

Comment: Hmm, I would have said "minimal" rather than "none" and more dependent on the row size rather than the column count (although the latter affects the former). With a larger row, your full table scan will not be able to get as many rows into memory with one read as it would with (e.g.) a row containing only the single column. So the _improvement_ of indexing that column is greater for a table with a row size of 50K than one with 10K row size. This difference would be swamped by other factors however, as you rightly point out.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Thanks. I'm using Postgres (latest version) and I have one table that I'll be doing a lot of `LIKE` type queries, etc but the values will undoubtedly change often since my clients have access to CRUD. Should I can the idea of indexes? Are they just a headache?

Comment: And a 50% reduction is nothing to sneeze at, if there is no better option, for example if your query is `select * from tbl where binaryfield = 1;`. It's up to the execution engine to find the index with the best cardinality so the search space can be reduced as quickly as possible. I do agree with your YAGNI on the unused indexes. This is what we pay DBAs for - to monitor and adjust these things on the fly.

Comment: @paxdiablo - it depends on the database product of course, but in Oracle a query which returns 50% of the rows will execute *way* faster as a full table scan than as an indexed read.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing LIKE queries you may find that indexes are not not much help anyway.  While an index might improve this query ...

```
select * from t23
where whatever like 'SOMETHING%'
/
```

... it is unlikely that an index will help with either of these queries ...

```
select * from t23
where whatever like '%SOMETHING%'
/

select * from t23
where whatever like '%SOMETHING'
/
```

If you have free text fields and your users need fuzzy matching then you should look at Postgres's full text functionality.  This employs the MATCH operator rather than LIKE and  which requires a special index type.  [Find out more.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html)

There is a gotcha, which is that full text indexes are more complicated than normal ones, and the [related design decisions are not simple](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-indexes.html).   Also some implementations require [additional maintenance activities](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS).

Comment: Why is it that a query would be sped up by the first one but not the second or third? I thought that the database would perform `like` searches in the same way but would be able to search from the indexed values instead of having the scan the whole table, essentially having the same effect on all 3 queries (this is my misunderstanding I'm sure, but I don't know why or how). I guess I don't understand how indexes speed things up then.

Comment: @orokusaki is it faster look up something in a phone book that ends in 'ith' or one that begins with 'Smi'? The second two examples can't use indexes becasue the first letter is not known. These types of queries should be avoided.

Comment: @HLGEM - Not to question your authority on this matter, but that doesn't seem like a valid comparison. Firstly, a table's data is not alphabetized for one. Secondly, a human cannot easily scan the last 3 characters of each name in the phone book, whereas a database can scan the last 3 characters of a column's data `data[length - 3] - data[length]` would seem a good way to put it (from a non DBA).